# add google ml-kit dependecy outside the app-level gradle file

Tags: google-mlkit

I'm following Googles [instructions](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/pose-detection/android#kotlin) on how to implement "Google ML Kit" into my application. It says

```
Before you begin
In your project-level build.gradle file, make sure to include Google's Maven repository in both your buildscript and allprojects sections.
Add the dependencies for the ML Kit Android libraries to your module's app-level gradle file, which is usually app/build.gradle:


dependencies {
  // If you want to use the base sdk
  implementation 'com.google.mlkit:pose-detection:17.0.1-beta6'
  // If you want to use the accurate sdk
  implementation 'com.google.mlkit:pose-detection-accurate:17.0.1-beta6'
}
```

However I need to use ML-Kit in a library outside my app. It's basically a java library that gets used from within my app. It also has a gradle file. However when I add the dependency there, I cannot import any ml-kit classes.

Here is the gradle file of my java library:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'


dependencies {

    api 'com.annimon:stream:1.2.2'

    api 'org.javatuples:javatuples:1.2'
    api 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'

    // JSON
    implementation 'org.json:json:20210307'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.12.4'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:pose-detection:17.0.1-beta6'
}

sourceCompatibility = "8"
targetCompatibility = "8"
```

gradle sync is still successful, but upon importing any class inside any other class of my java library, I get an import error:

```
import com.google.mlkit.vision.pose.defaults.PoseDetectorOptions;
```

--> cannot resolve symbol mlkit

Any idea what I could do about that?

Comment: Is this an issue specific to ML Kit or a general issue for gradle setup? Are you able to do this with other libraries?

Comment: For example, if this library is *the only one* depending on implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.3.1", could you import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData and build successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found the problem: The above gradle file belongs to a pure java library that is integrated into android later. ML-Kit apparantly cannot be used in Java projects. It only works if I integrate ML-Kit in pure android gradle projects